# How to ping a website using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network

Tags: .net, qtp

I have the below code which is written in QTP

```
Set oNetwork = DotNetFactory( "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network" ,"Microsoft.VisualBasic")
bFlag=oNetwork.ping(strWebSiteName)
If bFlag Then
   MsgBox( "Website is avilable" )
Else
   MsgBox( "Website not avilable" )
End If

Set oNetwork=nothing
```

But when I execute this code, I am getting the error below

```
Cannot load Assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices
Line (27): "Set oNetwork = DotNetFactory( "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network" ,"Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices")"
```

Can anybody tell me, what is going wrong?

.NET Framework 4 is already installed in my system.

Comment: Can you shell out to the command line ping?

Comment: The assembly name is `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, not `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices`. The code in your error message doesn't match the code sample you've posted. Also, have a look at: http://www.advancedqtp.com/ping-a-specified-server/

Comment: Corrected and worked fine, after changing to Microsoft.VisualBasic

Comment: @RichardDeeming please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The assembly name is `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, not `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices`. The code in your error message doesn't match the code sample you've posted.

Also, have a look at: http://www.advancedqtp.com/ping-a-specified-server/